# Launching OpenOffice from WPF app. AlwaysOnTop

Tags: c#, wpf, openoffice.org, always-on-top

I am launching openoffice 3.3.0 on Windows 7 from a WPF app no problem, however when launching on XP openoffice always goes behind my WPF any way to stop this ?

C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program\soffice.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing here.

Is there no way to launch a program and specify that it opens on-top/in-front?

Or do you need to minimize the WPF application to allow OO.o to show up on top.  You may just have gotten lucky on Windows 7.

Comment: Cant seem to find anything in OO settings

Comment: set a pif file and launched that instead, still a bit ropey but does the job